# Unit Test: throwing an error when access .pipe from subject()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing a test case and it is throwing an error that pipe is not a function

> this.panelService.outputEmitter.pipe is not a function

Here is my relevant code in typescript as well as in test cases:

**Typescript:**

```
constructor(private panelService: RightPanelService) {        
}

bulkAddCustomCapacitySchedule(roomIds) {
  this.panelService.create(CreateCustomCapacityScheduleComponent, {
    title: 'Add',
    subTitle: 'Custom Capacity Schedules',
    theme: 'success',
    emitterMethod: 'customCapacityScheduleSaveEdit',
    componentParams: { roomIdsArr: roomIds }
  });
  this.panelService.outputEmitter.pipe(takeUntil(this.outputSubscription)).subscribe((event: FilterTagModel) => {
    this.searchRoomConfiguration();
  });
}
```

---

RightPanelService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { PanelOptionsModel } from './panel-options.model';

@Injectable()
export class RightPanelService {
    panel = new Subject();
    loadingPanel = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
    outputEmitter = new Subject();
    panelContent: any = {
        isShowing: false,
        content: null,
        contentParams: PanelOptionsModel
    };

    constructor() {
    }
    public create(component: any, parameter?: PanelOptionsModel): any {
        this.panelContent.isShowing = true;
        this.panelContent.content = component;
        this.panelContent.contentParams = parameter;
        this.panel.next(this.panelContent);
    }
}
```

**Test Case:**

```
import { RoomConfigurationListComponent } from './room-configuration-list.component';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RightPanelService } from '../../../controls/right-panel/right-panel.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('RoomConfigurationListComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RoomConfigurationListComponent>;
  let mockPanelService, mockPreRequisiteService;
  let mockTagDropDownData;
  let mockRoomListData;
  let component: RoomConfigurationListComponent;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockPanelService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['showLoading', 'create', 'outputEmitter']);
    
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RoomConfigurationListComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [{
        provide: RightPanelService,
        useValue: mockPanelService
      }]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RoomConfigurationListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should call onBulkActionClick method', () => {
    spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'onBulkActionClick').and.callThrough();
    mockPreRequisiteService.GetDropdownsData.and.returnValue(of(mockTagDropDownData));
    component.selectedRows = mockRoomListData.items;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.componentInstance.onBulkActionClick();

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.onBulkActionClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the relevant typescript code, `outputEmitter` needs to return an `Observable`, in this case you would need to specify what to return for the particular function `outputEmitter`:

```
const mockPanelService = jasmine.createSpyObj<RightPanelService>(
'RightPanelService', [
  'showLoading', 
  'create', 
  'outputEmitter'
]);

beforeEach(() => mockPanelService.outputEmitter.and.returnValue(of({your: 'Value'})));

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [{ provide: RightPanelService, useValue: mockPanelService}]
  })
})
```

Comment: still it throws the same error, I tried it already and tried again.

Comment: @Sandip-FrontendDeveloper Notice the order I am creating the mock service, assigning the return value and then declare in providers... did you do it like that?